# How to get a circle position in a g element in SVG using D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a circle inside g element in the SVG. The g element can move simply according to the x-coordinates. The position of the g element can change as it moves. The circle also moves as it is in that g element. My question is how can I retrieve the position of that circle in the SVG NOT its position in g element? I tried the following code but could not get what I am expecting: `circleGroup.on("mouseover", function() 
        {
    var translate = d3.transform(d3.select(this).attr("transform")).translate;
    alert(translate[0].x);
        });`

May anyone assist me to retrieve the position of the circle in the SVG not in the g element, please? I need to get the position of the circle in order to draw a line starting from its position in the SVG not the g element where the circle is in. Your assistance would be very much appreciated. Here is: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mo_jsfiddle1/uo542s2e/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the position of the circle you moused-over, I would create my `.on` handler on the circles instead of the `g` element (this way you know which element received the event):

```
...
var circles = circleGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .data(circleData)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
...

function mouseover() {
   var self = d3.select(this);
   alert(self.attr('cx'));
}
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uo542s2e/1/).

EDITS FOR COMMENT

Opps, missed the transition.  How about:

```
function mouseover()
{
    var self = d3.select(this);
    var translate = d3.transform(self.attr("transform")).translate;
    alert(+self.attr('cx') + translate[0]);
}
```

Updated [fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/uo542s2e/2/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. The original position of both circles 20 and 70. After the transition of these two circles, I was expecting to get the new positions of them. Do you have any idea how I can get these values?

Comment: Mark. Thank you very much for your assistance. My problem is now I can't apply your code to the real code I am having right now. I need to figure it out. Once again, thank you very much for your help.